# How to remove all comments on IDLE, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, comments

I really want to remove all comments like: `#This does this` for example, as I annotated it ages ago, and I want to try and work out what all the parts of the code do, without going through 600+ lines and deleting them individually.

Comment: Since IDLE doesn't have a "remove all comments" menu item, I don't think this question really has anything to do with IDLE. You could have equivalently asked "how do I remove comments from a Python script?" without making any mention of the IDE.

Comment: In the interpreter, or the editor? You can easily make another program to remove comments.

Comment: Use an editor that supports regex search and replace, e.g. in vim I could naively do `:%s/#.*$//g` [assuming there are no '#'s in string literals].

Comment: oh, what a miracle. Posted an answer for a question which is marked as dupe  25 mins ago.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi The editor. Is that not what IDLE is?

Comment: Yes, I mean which mode: interactive or scripting.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi The scripting mode. I am still new to programming in general, and I have no idea how to do this without wasting a lot of time deleting each line.

Comment: Do you have any hash tags in strings?

Comment: Then use a for loop to iterate through the lines, find a hashtag, and remove everything after.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi That's why I was asking, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Well you'll need to reopen the question so that I can write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you could use re module.

```
>>> s = """foo bar
#This does this
 # foo bar
bar foo"""
>>> for i in s.split('\n'):
        if not re.match(r'\s*#', i):
            print(i)


foo bar
bar foo
```

Comment: Probably better to use `\s*` before the `#`, in case the OP (or some future visitor) uses tabs. Also, note that this will struggle with e.g. multiline strings *within* the code.

Comment: since we are splitting the input according to the `\n` chaarcter, `\s*` at the start won't create any problems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't answer my question - I meant how to remove them in the script editor, which I thought was called IDLE. I will edit my question for this.